# ASP.NET Reusable User Controls Across Different Assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, msbuild-target

We are currently developing several Web projects and would like to be able to create a project that includes User Controls shared across the Web projects instead of having to recreate them. From what I found out, the process overall [is a pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363736/user-controls-assembly-in-different-projects) since each project needs to have access to the actual `ascx` file and not just a reference to it.

My way of approaching this is:

### 1- Use Pre-Build events to copy .ascx files

from the shared assembly into current project's working folder. This works fine for **debugging the application**, but we need to do the same thing during a **file-system publish**.

### 2- Use MSBuild targets to copy .ascx files druing a publish

I added the following target to my project's configuration file:

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish" AfterTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
   <Exec Command="xcopy.exe SourcePath OutputPath" />
</Target>
```

(Note that `SourcePath` and `TargetPath` are full paths to the directories. I replaced them here to make it shorter)

This target gets called after a file-system publish (right-click on the project -> Publish), however, files don't get copied to the destination folder.

I've confirmed that the target gets called (by changing `Command=explorer.exe`, a Windows Explorer window pops up) and also ran the `xcopy.exe` command with the same exact paths on `CommandPrompt` and it did work fine. So I don't understand why it doesn't work as part of the target. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to check your publish options and make sure that the "Delete all existing files prior to publish"
[image: Publish Options]

The problem is the xcopy command always gets executed before the deletion happens, so they get copied but delete right after.

If you need a clean folder each time I suggest you put everything in your "AfterBuild"

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

<Exec Command="echo @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Clean Publish Folder @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" />
<Exec Command="echo $(PublishUrl)" />
<Exec Command="echo Publish Folder Deleted...." Condition="Exists('$(PublishUrl)')"/>
<!--<Exec Command="del /q $(PublishUrl)\*" Condition="Exists('$(PublishUrl)')"/>-->
<!--<Exec Command="FOR /D %%p IN (&quot;$(PublishUrl)*.*&quot;) DO rmdir &quot;%%p&quot; /s /q" />-->
<Exec Command="del /q $(PublishUrl)\*" Condition="Exists('$(PublishUrl)')"/>
<Exec Command="FOR /D %%p IN (&quot;$(PublishUrl)\*.*&quot;) DO rmdir &quot;%%p&quot; /s /q" />
<Exec Command="echo Publish Folder Creation...." Condition="Exists('$(PublishUrl)')"/>
<Exec Command="mkdir $(PublishUrl)" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishUrl)')"/>
<Exec Command="echo @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Copying @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" />
<Exec Command="xcopy.exe SourceDir DestinationDir /S /E /H" />

</Target>
```

Comment: This actually did it. Yeah I was deleting all the files prior to publish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild has a Copy task. Try the following:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySource Include='path\to\files\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySource)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputDir)\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I tried `Copy` before `xcopy`. That didn't work either. I wonder if it's some timing issue.